# Joining views in android

Tags: android, overlay

My problem is the following:
I'm building an app for android in which i have an image , and on top of that i should draw some rectangles.

By now i already have the image in an imageview working, and another view with the rectangles(and some motionevent working with it).I wanted now to join those two views, to have the image, and the other view properties(like the drawing and motionevents functionalities)

I read and tested something about layout inflater ,and tried to make the view on top tranparent but didnt work. so if anyone have some guidelines I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423530/combine-two-contentviews

Comment: Thanks, but in that merge example , for what i understood, it only works with layout's build on the xml file,right? I'm doing one layout through xml and the another through code(i think it's called a custom view) is that possible to merge too?

Comment: You should be able to define your custom View in XML as well. Example: <com.mypackagename.customviewclass android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... etc />  combined with the link i commented above should work for you.